# Model.reject() results invalid fields in extjs form

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm using Extjs 5.1.

I have a form which is bind to view model. 
My form has few mandatory fields. 
To reset form values am using model.reject() method.

When I enter a value in mandatory field and click reset button, it results invalid field with red colour border.

I have created a fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/u2h) for your reference. You can test this by entering a value into the input field and then click on reset button. Then field becomes invalid with red colour border.

How to get rid of this invalid field issue on reset ?

Answer (score 1):

1. set Custom panel to extend Ext.form.Panel instead of Ext.Panel
2. add me.reset() in line 62, after co.reject();

Comment: It's an older issue, but this works for Ext JS 6.0.2